# Dynamic grid in Angular

Tags: angular, angular-material

What is a general approach to creating a dynamically sized grid (table, Excel like) of cells in Angular 8? Looking at Angular Material table implementation gave some insight but it is not easy to read.

Comment: Usually most grid controls have options to customize column definitions. I’d start with picking a grid control you want to use. Yes, you could build your own grid components, but that’s a little unnecessary. Otherwise, welcome to the great world of CSS.

Comment: use this out of the box
https://js.devexpress.com/Demos/WidgetsGallery/Demo/DataGrid/CustomizeKeyboardNavigation/Angular/MaterialBlueLight/Compact/